# performance of declaring objects

Tags: c++, performance, std

I was coding in some sort of university conquest and noticed something, when I declare a map in a loop such as down below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    map<int, bool> hashMap;
    //...
}
```

it takes more time than:

```
map<int, bool> hashMap;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    hashMap.clear();
    //...
}
```

so I was wondering why does declaring an object in a loop has worse performance than just re-initializing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first version of the code the constructor and destructor of the `hashMap` are called `n` times, while in the second version they are called just once.

The natural question is why destructing and constructing a new `map` object would be noticeably different vs. clearing and reusing one and the same object. This can be definitively answered only by inspecting the actual `map` code of the implementation being used, so the following is just a plausible guess.

[`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is usually implemented using [red-black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), and it is common for red-black tree implementations to use a [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) node for NIL-leaves, see for example [Benefit of a sentinel node in a red black tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45739238/benefit-of-a-sentinel-node-in-a-red-black-tree). This sentinel must be allocated each time a tree is constructed, then released upon destruction. In contrast, `clear`'ing a `map`, instead, empties the tree but reuses the associated internal objects.

For a real-life example of such an implementation, Microsoft's [`_Tree`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/xtree#L885) constructor calls the aptly named `_Alloc_sentinel_and_proxy();`. Since their `map` derives from `_Tree`, this gets called each time a `map` object is constructed.

Comment: It would be interesting to dump the assembly and compare the overhead of construction with that of destruction. I suspect, without have done the comparison, that the construction overhead is probably the greater of the two by several times over. The cumulative effect of having that within the loop only compounds the problem.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Offhand, I would expect the heavier part to be about memory operations where, indeed, allocations cost more than deallocations.